# Undefined index: id when retrieving data from data column in notification table- Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, cron, schedule

```
nav.blade.php

<div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right"
                    aria-labelledby="messagesDropdown">
                    <a style="color: green;" class="dropdown-item" href="#">
                        @foreach($user->unreadNotifications as $notifications)
                        <a href="">{{$notifications->data['name']['id']}}</a>
                        @endforeach
                    </a><!--  <a style="color: red;" class="dropdown-item" href="#"> <i
                        class="fas fa-plus"></i> &nbsp Add Lost Item
                    </a> -->

                </div>
```

I'm getting an error when retrieving the id from the data column please help me. I just want to get the item id and the name from data column in the notification table. if any one know please help me i'm new to laravel

Comment: public function toDatabase($notifiable)
    {
        
        return [

            'name' => Item::where('expire_date' , '=' , Carbon::now()->addDays(1)->toDateString())->get()->toArray(),
        
 
          
                
        ];
    }

Comment: print "user->unreadNotifications" array in controller and check key are available or not.

Comment: dd(auth()->user()->unreadnotifications); gives null dd(auth()->user()->notifications) shows the value

Comment: Please upload the result

Comment: Can you show your controller code here

Comment: I didn't use controller to send notifications. I used cron jobs

Answer (score 0):

> I just want to get the item id and the name from data column in the notification table

I don't know how you save multiple values (name and ID) in the same column.

I think there are two options:

### The item itself has column *id* and column *name*

In this case, there's no need to access the *data* column. It should be:

```
<a href="">{{$notifications->name}} , {{$notifications->id}}</a>
```

### Saving name and ID in column data as JSON object

In that case, you need to parse this JSON value before using it. 
Also, `$notifications->data['name']['id']` means that data['name'] is an object that has an attribute called *id* and there's no attribute holding the value of item *name*, and I don't think you mean that. The correct implementation is

```
<a href="">{{Json.decode($notifications->data)['name']}} , {{Json.decode($notifications->data)['id']}}</a>
```